# Choosing an optimal generator for an irreducible polynomial over a binary field?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am reading the [Certicom tutorial “An Example of an Elliptic Curve Group over F2m ”](https://www.certicom.com/41-an-example-of-an-elliptic-curve-group-over-f2m) and I have following questions:

1. How do they assume that generator $g = (0010)$ is correct for this polynomial?
2. How can/should one choose an optimal generator from a group of generators for a specific field?

Comment: The lazy man's way to pick up a small polynomial with this or that characteristic is to lookup the appropriate list in [Joerg Arndt's useful and ugly page of mathematical data](http://www.jjj.de/mathdata/). For example, your irreducible polynomial $x^4+x+1$ is the line reading `4,1,0` in the [Complete list of binary irreducible polynomials up to degree 11](http://www.jjj.de/mathdata/all-irredpoly.txt).

Comment: define "optimal"

Comment: @Przemek, do the answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a *primitive* polynomial of degree $m$ (for using with $\operatorname{GF}(2^m)$).

This is an irreducible polynomial whose roots have maximal multiplicative order $2^m-1.$

There are tables of these, at least one is guaranteed to exist for each degree. Alternatively they can be found by randomised methods. Use a polynomial factorisation algorithm to get an irreducible of degree $m$, say $f(X)$  and then check that $$X^i \bmod f(X)\neq 1$$ for any proper divisors $i,~1<i<2^m-1$, of $2^m-1.$

If you know one such polynomial with a root $X$ then its roots are $X,X^2,\ldots , X^{2^{m-1}}$ each with multiplicity 1. By trying $X^u$ with $\gcd(u, 2^m-1)=1$ you may find a lower weight polynomial to enable efficient implementation, just write the new polynomial as 
$$
f_u(z)=(Z-X^u)(Z-X^{2u})(Z-X^{2^{m-1}u})
$$
and simplify over $\operatorname{GF}(2).$

**Edit:** Error in last equation corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Each $\text{GF}(2^n)$ is guaranteed to have one or more generators and one or more associated irreducible polynomial. For $\text{GF}(2^4)$,  $0010$, i.e., $2$ represented as a 4-bit number is a generator $g$ (more specifically, multiplicative generator) since $g$ repeatedly multiplied with itself, i.e.,

$$1 = g^0=0001$$
$$g = g^1 = 0010$$ 
$$g*g = g^2=0100$$ 
$$g*g*g = g^3 = 1000$$ 
$$g*g*g*g = g^4=1,0000$$ 
$$g*g*g*g*g = g^5 = 10,0000$$
$$...$$ 
$$g^{15}$$

create all the elements of $\text{GF}(2^4) = \{0,1,.., 15\}$. Note however that every element of $\text{GF}(2^4)$ needs to be represented as a polynomial for doing arithmetic, e.g., multiply (*). So, $g^4 = 2^4 = 10000$, which in polynomial form is $2^4$ or $x^4$ in general, $g^5 = $. Now, $\text{GF}(2^4)$ has three irreducible polynomials, viz. $x^4+x+1$, $x^4+x^2+1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. If we select $x^4+x+1$ as our irreducible polynomial, then polynomials have be computed mod $x^4+x+1$. So,

$$x^4 \text{mod} (x^4+x+1) = x+1 = 0011 = 3$$
$$x^5 \text{mod} (x^4+x+1) = x^2 + x = 0110 = 6$$
$$...$$
$$x^{14} \text{mod} (x^4+x+1) = x^3+ 1 = 1001 = 9$$
$$x^{15} \text{mod} (x^4+x+1) = 1 = 0001 = 1$$

Therefore, it turns out that $2$ or $0010$ is able to generate all elements $\{0,1,..15\}$. Now to answer your specific question, in general for, any $\text{GF}(p)$ ($p$ prime), one has test out which element(s) $g$ in $\text{GF}(p)$ can generate all elements of $\text{GF}(p)$. However, for any $\text{GF}(2^n)$, $2$ is guaranteed to be one of the generators and is preferred since coefficients of any polynomial term is $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Actually, 2 (aka $x^1$) is *not* guaranteed to be one of the generators (that is, generate all nonzero elements); for example, for the irreducible polynomial $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$, 2 generates only 5 elements.

Comment: Also, correction for a typo: $x^4 + x^2 + 1 = (x^2 + x + 1) \cdot (x^2 + x + 1)$ is not irreducible; you meant $x^4 + x^3 + 1$

Comment: While it's not entirely wrong, I would suggest getting rid of using decimal representation of binary numbers which are realized as congruence classes of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$. It is misleading in the sense that while there is also an addition, it is not the addition of integers but actually XOR in the binary representation, which is the coefficient vector for the polynomials (or better: their congruence classes) . Using decimal integers like $\{0,1,\dots,15\}$ might be mistaken for $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$.